# Changing global objects while still being able to validate arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

Currently I have 2 global variables within my python module. I wanted to get away from using the global variable scope, while still being able to call the 2 variables throughout my module. Basically what's the best way to get away from the global object, while still being able to validate arguments.

I tried creating a class within a function, which i realized wouldnt work.

global gl_args 
global gl_hashType

gl_args 1⁄4 parser.parse_args()

```
if gl_args.md5:
    gl_hashType = 'MD5'
elif gl_args.sha256:
    gl_hashType = 'SHA256'
elif gl_args.sha512:
    gl_hashType = 'SHA512'
elif gl_args.sha224:
    gl_hashType = 'SHA224'
elif gl_args.sha384:
    gl_hashType = 'SHA384'
else:
    gl_hashType = "Unknown"
    logging.error('Unknown Hash Type Specified')

DisplayMessage("Command line processed: Successfully")

return
```

## this is only one piece of where it is used but the 2 variables are used throughout the program.

Calling the variable throughout the module.

Comment: I just want to be able to call those 2 variables  currently declared as "global gl_args global gl_hashType" throughout my entire python module without using the global scope. Just tips on the best way to declare a class that can do that.

Comment: dont put a class inside the function, put the function inside a class.  (and the variables inside the class)

Comment: Christian Sloper if I have multiple functions that were using those variables should in just make different classes for those functions?

Comment: put all the (relevant) functions inside one class

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a class

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self,x,y):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y

    def f1(self):
        return self.x + self.y

    def f2(self):
        return self.y - self.x

    def area(self):
        return self.y*self.x
```

used like this:

```
my_instance = MyClass(4,5)

my_instance.f1()
my_instance.f2()
```